# iOS Why can't the method collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath: be called from UITapGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I've set up a UITapGestureRecognizer for a UIScrollView inside a UICollectionView. I've configured it to properly detect taps and trigger a method I wrote, but if I try to set the selector to collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath: the program crashes when a cell is tapped.

Any idea why this is the case?

**This works:**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];

- (void) tapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
//some code
}
```

**This does not work:**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:)];

- (void) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//some code
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the code you wrote,

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:)];
```

The selector is generally just a singleFunction with one input argument which is `UITapGestureRecogniser` object.

should be like this,

```
-(void)clicked:(UIGestureRecogniser *)ges{

}
```

But the selector you used it improper, because it needs two inputs which cant be supplied with gestureRecogniser.Hence the crash.

Change your above code to below one,

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(clicked:)];
-(void)clicked:(UIgestureRecogniser *)ges{
    //use gesture to get get the indexPath, using CGPoint (locationInView). 
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = ...;
    [self collectionView:self.collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The action for a gesture recognizer must conform to one of the following signatures:

```
- (void)handleGesture;
- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
```

You need to use one of these action signatures and do whatever you need to in that method
, including determining the correct `indexPath` for the gesture.

See the docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIGestureRecognizer/initWithTarget:action:

Answer (score 0):

We have to call the didSelectItemAtIndexPath from the proper reference object.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];

- (void) tapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture{

      NSIndexPath *indexPath =    //create your custom index path here

      [self.collectionViewObject didSelectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

}
```